# Bash script works in terminal emulator, but not as i3 keybind

Tags: linux, bash, archlinux, i3

I have a lock screen script (via i3lock) that runs correctly in a terminal window, but not when used as a keybind in i3 config.

The script is pretty straightforward:

```
# Take screenshot
scrot /tmp/screenshot.png

# Pixelate and add central logo
magick /tmp/screenshot.png -scale 10% -scale 1000% -gravity center /home/user/bin/archlogo.png -composite /tmp/lock.png

# Lock using pixelated image & logo
i3lock -e -f -c 000000 -i /tmp/lock.png
```

The script is saved to `~/bin/lock` and executable. The directory has also been identified in my `~/.bash_profile`.

There is no error message, only brief flash of the terminal cursor.

The relevant lines in `~/.config/i3/config`:

```
# lock screen
bindsym $mod+l exec lock
```

(the default keybind for $mod+l was deleted and i3 was restarted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~/.bash_profile` is a configuration file for `bash` and as such is only loaded when `bash` starts (as an interactive login shell or when it is expclicitly sourced by other bash configuration files, e.g. `~/.bashrc`). `i3` itself does not load anything from `~/.bash_profile` and neither does *X.org*. So unless you start your X session from a bash shell (for example with `startx` from the console) any changes to PATH will not have been loaded and `i3` will not know about `~/bin` being added to `PATH`.

If you want to modify `PATH` for `i3` itself, then `~/.bash_profile` is not the right place. Unfortunately for X sessions the "right place" very much depends on how you start it (e.g. from the console with `start` or with some desktop manager like `lightdm` or `kdm`).

You could add a setting for `PATH` to `~/.pam_environment`, which - at least on Arch - should prepend the given value to the system default setting of `PATH`. For example, if you put the follwing in your `~/.pam_environment`

```
PATH=/home/soundscape/bin
```

and the default value is

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

you will end up with

```
/home/soundscape/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

Of course, this value might be further modified by any settings in `~/.bash_profile` or similar files when you start `bash`.

**Note:** `~/.pam_environment` does not support any parameter expansion, so adding something like

```
PATH=${PATH}:${HOME}/bin
```

will **not** work.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It makes a lot of sense. With your note in mind, I used the suggestion below of specifying `exec ${HOME}/bin/lock` and it works great. I'll leave the $PATH environment variable as-is for future non-WM-related scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I remember something similar... try specifying the absolute path like this, might be that `exec` doesn't honor the `$PATH` environment variable:

```
# lock screen
bindsym $mod+l exec "${HOME}/bin/lock"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It worked a treat, and makes sense with what Adaephon noted above.